# How to reduce boilerplate in responseJSON just like I use URLRequestConvertible to group related web calls

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I use URLRequestConvertible to groups my web calls, and to reduce the boilerplate code. But in each responseJSON I still have boilerplate to process my JSON response. They all look like these,

1. Check response.result.isSuccess
2. Check response.result.value as? the type data I expect (mostly a dictionary)
3. Check for the success indicator in dictionary
4. If succeed then retrieve the data I need.

And because I group the related calls in one URLRequestConvertible, their responses have the similar format that I actually have the 5th step to further retrieve the "real" data I am looking for.

So is there any way to reduce these boilerplate codes in responseJSON?

BTW, I actually come up with a kludge solution for it. But I was wondering is there any common practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

I raised the same question at [alamofire forum #2099](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2099) and got the answer to use **ResponseSerializer**

But after check the ResponseSerializer document I realize my home-made solution was not as crappy as I thought (using ResponseSerializer seems rather complicated)

So my solution is to add a static verify method to my Router and let it do the basic verification work (from Step #1 to Step #5)

```
static func verify(json:DataResponse<Any>, request:Router) -> result //needs the 2nd
parameter b/c is a static method
```

Now my calling method changed to these,

```
var result = CallResult.fail
Alamofire.request(Router.Callback(input))
         .responseJSON { response in
            result = Router.verify(json:response,request:Router.Callback(input))
         }
         .responseJSON { _ in //AS I already parsed response into my result
            //process the result now
         }
```